# Click on link should go to particular tab in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui-router, angular8

When i click below link, it should redirect to another page and open a particular tab.

HTML - it should go to myprofile page password tab

```
<a routerLink="/myprofile" href="javascript:;" class="kt-notification__item">
    <div class="kt-notification__item-icon">
        <span class="iconify" data-icon="simple-line-icons:key" data-inline="false"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="kt-notification__item-details">
        <div class="kt-notification__item-title kt-font-bold">
            Password
        </div>
        <div class="kt-notification__item-time">
            Change your password
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: is your navigation working?

Comment: have u configured routing ??

Comment: navigation is working moving to the correct page,but it should move to particular tab,please help me

Comment: why are you adding 'href' attribute ? Remove it.
Angular adds href for routerLink at runtime. 
What do you mean by particular tab ?

Comment: @Yogendra123  ok i removed href and added routerLink,it should go to profile page,in that profile page there is two tab,it should go to second tab.

Comment: Ok, How you implemented tab, what is it ? your own implementation or some third party, please share code or create stackblitz demo

Comment: Create stackblitz of your code. Here : `https://stackblitz.com/`

Comment: this is tab section,while clicking it should come here(while clicking div,page should redirect and should move on to password div which is in the redirected page)<div class="kt-portlet__head-label">
                                 <h3 class="kt-portlet__head-title">   Change password </h3>
                              </div>

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding a query param to your route:

```
@ViewChild(MatTabGroup, {static: true}) tabGroup: MatTabGroup;

constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe((data) => {
    if(data.index && (data.index === '0' || data.index=== '1')) {
      this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = data.index;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(
        [], 
        {
          relativeTo: this.route,
          queryParams: { index: '0' },
          queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
      });
    }
  });
}

tabChanged(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.router.navigate(
      [], 
      {
        relativeTo: this.route,
        queryParams: { index: event.index },
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    });
}
```

In the HTML file implement that `tabChanged` method for updating the query param:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
    // some content
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
    // some content
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Now you can navigate to this tab with follwing router link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/myprofile']" [queryParams]="{index: '1'}">Somewhere</a>
```